# android webview webapp stop working on a specific device

Tags: android, webview

Our android webview webapp working on all  devices without any problem. On a specific device not working and displays "system ui has stopped" , Logs are here:

```
12-11 10:24:12.071 19640-19640/? I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Document was loaded from Application Cache with manifest https://app.powerbi.com/OfflineSupport/ManifestDashboard/cache.manifest", source: https://app.powerbi.com/dashboard?manifest=OfflineSupport%2FManifestDashboard%2Fcache.manifest&clusterUri=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.powerbi.com%2F&hostType=android&disableClientTelemetry=true (0)
12-11 10:24:12.071 19640-19640/? I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache Checking event", source: https://app.powerbi.com/dashboard?manifest=OfflineSupport%2FManifestDashboard%2Fcache.manifest&clusterUri=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.powerbi.com%2F&hostType=android&disableClientTelemetry=true (0)
12-11 10:24:15.521 19640-19640/? I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache NoUpdate event", source: https://app.powerbi.com/dashboard?manifest=OfflineSupport%2FManifestDashboard%2Fcache.manifest&clusterUri=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.powerbi.com%2F&hostType=android&disableClientTelemetry=true (0)
12-11 10:24:17.081 19640-19640/? I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(136)] "TypeError: Cannot read property 'AccessToken' of undefined
                                                 at https://app.powerbi.com/13.0.1700.762/scripts/powerbimobilecommon.min.js:1:27377
                                                 at https://app.powerbi.com/13.0.1700.762/scripts/powerbiportal.dependencies.bundle.min.js:149:20
                                                 at m.$eval (https://app.powerbi.com/13.0.1700.762/scripts/powerbiportal.dependencies.bundle.min.js:163:347)
                                                 at m.$digest (https://app.powerbi.com/13.0.1700.762/scripts/powerbiportal.dependencies.bundle.min.js:160:422)
                                                 at https://app.powerbi.com/13.0.1700.762/scripts/powerbiportal.dependencies.bundle.min.js:163:435
                                                 at e (https://app.powerbi.com/13.0.1700.762/scripts/powerbiportal.dependencies.bundle.min.js:63:452)
                                                 at https://app.powerbi.com/13.0.1700.762/scripts/powerbiportal.dependencies.bundle.min.js:66:301", source: https://app.powerbi.com/13.0.1700.762/scripts/powerbiportal.dependencies.bundle.min.js (136)
```

above url is not on my app at all.

After search on google, I added these lines:

```
final WebSettings webviewSettings = webView.getSettings();
final String appCachePath = this.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
webviewSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
webviewSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
webviewSettings.setAppCachePath(appCachePath);
webviewSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
```

And

```
12-11 11:57:28.242 31238-31238/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.android.systemui.recents, PID: 31238
                                                   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 20492 byte allocation with 6912 free bytes and 6KB until OOM
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Array.createMultiArray(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Array.java:335)
                                                       at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getAppIconAlphaRelativeScale(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2989)
                                                       at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getThemeIconWithBG(ApplicationPackageManager.java:3107)
                                                       at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getThemeIconWithBG(ApplicationPackageManager.java:3037)
                                                       at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.loadUnbadgedItemIcon(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2867)
                                                       at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.loadItemIcon(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2774)
                                                       at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadIcon(PackageItemInfo.java:220)
                                                       at com.android.systemui.recents.misc.SystemServicesProxy.getActivityIcon(SystemServicesProxy.java:793)
                                                       at com.android.systemui.recents.model.RecentsTaskLoader.getAndUpdateActivityIcon(RecentsTaskLoader.java:463)
                                                       at com.android.systemui.recents.model.RecentsTaskLoadPlan.executePlan(RecentsTaskLoadPlan.java:279)
                                                       at com.android.systemui.recents.model.RecentsTaskLoader.loadTasks(RecentsTaskLoader.java:621)
                                                       at com.android.systemui.recents.Recents.onStart(Recents.java:393)
                                                       at com.android.systemui.recents.Recents.handleProxyCall(Recents.java:822)
                                                       at com.android.systemui.recents.Recents.handleProxyCall(Recents.java:744)
                                                       at com.android.systemui.recents.Recents.start(Recents.java:347)
                                                       at com.android.systemui.recents.Recents.getInstanceAndStartIfNeeded(Recents.java:322)
                                                       at com.android.systemui.recents.RecentsService.onCreate(RecentsService.java:39)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3807)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:221)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1882)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
12-11 11:57:30.172 20255-28583/? E/SCLOUD_ERR-AuthControl_[CT86173145]: TID : [97332] auth exception
                                                                        com.samsung.android.scloud.framework.PDMException: auth data is not valid.., eCode : 305
                                                                            at com.samsung.android.scloud.auth.result.AuthControl$1.run(AuthControl.java:54)
                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

But problem still exists, Please advice.

Comment: please paste the full logs. which is the device that crashes?

Comment: @peshkira Device is Samsung Galaxy S6 edge, I don't have access to full log at the moment.

Comment: @peshkira full log is added.

Comment: Your device is running out of memory. That is why your app crashes. This can have many different reasons. One can be, that the web page you are loading causes this, but it is not necessarily the case. Have you tried to use hardware acceleration on your webview?